# Como posso criar imagens com varios tamanhos no wordpress (na pasta upload) inserindo imagens de forma manual?

Tags: wordpress, imagem, upload

Boas, estou migrando um website de notícias de bootstrap para wordpress, já fiz o site e carreguei todos os posts  e as imagens, porem as imagens somente tem um único tamanho (não existem várias replicas da imagem com diversos tamanhos), como posso criar varias imagens com multiplos tamanhos?

**Na imagem em anexo está o exemplo do que pretendo fazer:**

[image: Exemplo do que pretendo]

Temos a imagem: **ao-aque-site-.png** - ao fazer upload na biblioteca do wordpress automaticamente são criadas outras imagens com varios tamanhos. Pretendo fazer isso para imagens que não foram carregadas directamente da biblioteca do wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem várias formas de se (re)criar os thumbnails. A mais fácil é com plugins, mas também será a mais lenta. Uma alternativa seria usar a cli do wordpress, por exemplo. Ou, caso utilize uma CDN com capacidade de gerar as imagens dinamicamente, nem seria necessário ter todas as imagens no seu servidor.

#### Plugin

Um exemplo de plugin é o [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/). Basta instalar e ativar este plugin, abrir a sua interface na administração, selecionar as opções adequadas para o seu caso e apertar em "Generate thumbnails". Ele fará todo o trabalho sozinho.

#### WP CLI

Como instalar a cli do Wordpress vai depender do seu sistema operacional e está fora do escopo desta pergunta. Entretanto, uma vez instalada, basta usar o comando `wp media regenerate --yes`.

#### Tamanhos gerados

Note que nesses casos serão geradas as imagens para os tamanhos definidos por padrão no Wordpress e no seu template (caso especificado). Os tamanhos do Wordpress são

- Thumbnail (150px x 150px);
- Médio (até 300px de altura ou largura);
- Grande (até 1024px de altura ou largura);
- Original (imagem original).

Para adicionar novos tamanhos, pode-se usar o método `add_image_size` no arquivo functions.php do seu template.

#### CDN

O Wordpress oferece um plano gratuito do plugin [Site accelerator](https://jetpack.com/support/site-accelerator/) que inclui o uso ilimitado de uma CDN, bem como outras funcionalidades.

---

Um detalhe sobre a sua pergunta. Não faz muito sentido dizer que está migrando de Bootstrap para Wordpress. Uma coisa não tem relação com a outra e o seu tema do Wordpress pode usar Bootstrap. É como mudar de casa e pintar as paredes da mesma cor que a casa anterior.

Comment: Muito obrigado, resultou

Comment: Obrigado pelo nota sobre a pergunta!